# Layout handle in transactinoal email not using the right theme

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, transactional-mail

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

The above block/layout handle in my transactional email is using the base theme when the invoice is created - however strangely when the invoice is resent, it uses the correct theme. Both actions are being carried out in the admin.

I've tried:

```
{{layout area="frontend" package="foo" theme="bar" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

but have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that just setting the 'Default' value under `Configuration > General > Design` is not quite enough for the transactional emails to use the correct theme. I needed to fill everything out:

[image]